# Google Cloud Platform BigQuery Streaming

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to follow the example below to stream data into a BigQuery table.

```
# TODO(developer): Uncomment the lines below and replace with your values.
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()
# dataset_id = 'my_dataset'  # replace with your dataset ID
# For this sample, the table must already exist and have a defined schema
# table_id = 'my_table'  # replace with your table ID
# table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
# table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API request

rows_to_insert = [
    (u'Phred Phlyntstone', 32),
    (u'Wylma Phlyntstone', 29),
]

errors = client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)  # API request

assert errors == []
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

zip argument #2 must support iteration

I suspect that there is some misalignment between my table schema and the data entry schema. Could anybody tell me exactly how I can query each of these schemas so I can see where the differences are please?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Can you include the entire stack trace?

Comment: Hi, apologies for my ignorance but what exactly do you mean by the "entire stack trace"?

Comment: Where was the error raised? Usually you should see multiple lines of the error, the stack trace is everything from `Traceback (most recent call last):` to the line `zip argument #2 must support iteration`

Comment: @Py_J try making the rows to insert a dict with the appropriate field names as keys?